# Show current post's tag in the "view more..." button

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a site for a travel company and have hit a stumbling block.

When viewing a blog page the sidebar has a 'view more..' button which need to change depending on the tag of the current post. For example, the current blog post could be an article about travel in India so the side bar button needs to read "More on India" which then links to search results including the tag 'India'. If the current post is tagged 'China', the link needs to read "More on China" and link to search results tagged 'china'.... and so on...

Can anyone advise how I achieve this?

Comment: Since you haven't provided your code. You can pass your `tag` variable from ajax and load records on the basis of that `tag` in backend.

Comment: There is no code as of yet, just a series of wordpress blog posts relating to different areas of the world.I guess what I'm looking for is a way to echo either a post's tag or category and then use that echo to create a search. Sorry if that doesnt really answer your question regarding tag variables but I'm not really sure how else to answer.

Comment: I've resolved this using get_the_category() and get_category_link()